# Card Reader and Software

Tags: security, login, usb

I am looking for a card-reader solution that includes not only the physical card-reader but a method to read/program the cards.  The end goal is have to give my end users a card-reader and then an associated card they need to swipe to login to the windows machine.  I am not worried about end-users 'swapping' cards as they are geographically distant.

Suggestions on where to start?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

A simple swipe card is easy to [skim and then clone](http://videos.howstuffworks.com/www-insideidtheft-info/31902-credit-card-skimmer-exposed-video.htm).  Often simple magnetic strip readers just contain a secret which is transmitted over usb or ps/2 which could be intercepted by a [hardware key logger](http://www.keydevil.com/).   [Smart card authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380142(VS.85).aspx) isn't affected by this attack.   Even if the challenge response was intercepted,  the attacker would have to brute force the private key.   Here is [more information](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Multifactor-authentication-Windows-Part1.html) on implementing two factor authentication for windows.

Comment: I agree that two-factor authentication is the way to go; however that is not my assignment.  I'm simply supposed to find a card-reader solution, even if it is one-factor, and I don't know where to look.

Comment: @Robert if the three links i posted isn't enough information then i'm sorry but i don't think anyone can help.   A smartcard has doesn't require multi-factor authentication.  Apples and oranges, mag strips are **EXTREMELY** insecure and are trivial to clone, this would be massive mistake.

Comment: I can agree that is not secure by any means, but this is where policy makers meet security people and win.  :/